# Why doesn't this loop work

Tags: c

I want to make a program to sum scores and find the highest scores by using a two-dimensional array.
I faced some strange thing without any error.
I found that the loop (with cla, stu variable) seems be skipped.
I tried to print something on every loop, but I couldn't find the reason.
I work on Visual Studio 2017 in Windows 7.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define makeScore() (rand() % 60 + 40);

int main() {

    int arScore[2][3];
    int cla, stu;
    int sum[2];
    int maxScore = 0;
    int maxc = 0, maxs = 0;
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(arScore) / sizeof(arScore[0]); i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < sizeof(arScore[0]) / sizeof(arScore[0][0]); j++) {
            arScore[i][j] = makeScore();
        }
    }

    for (cla = 0; i < sizeof(arScore) / sizeof(arScore[0]); cla++) {
        sum[cla] = 0;

        for (stu = 0; j < sizeof(arScore[0]) / sizeof(arScore[0][0]); stu++) {
            sum[cla] += arScore[cla][stu];

            if (maxScore < arScore[cla][stu]) {
                maxScore = arScore[cla][stu];
                maxc = cla;
                maxs = stu;
            }
        }
        printf("the total score of %d class : %d\n", cla + 1, sum[cla]);
    }

    puts("the student with the highest score");
    printf("%d class, %d student, %d score\n", maxc, maxs, maxScore);

    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a proper problem description. Please give the expected output and actual output. And what have you done to debug the problem yourself?

Comment: I think you mean "maximum" not "roof". But still your question is unclear. In what way doesn't it work? What is happening (with specific inputs) and what do you expect (with those inputs).

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Actually It's my first time to post the question. so now I changed my question to be specification. Thanks a lot

Comment: Part of your problem is the checks on the loops: `for (cla = 0; i < sizeof(arScore) / sizeof(arScore[0]); cla++) {
      sum[cla] = 0;
    
      for (stu = 0; j < sizeof(arScore[0]) / sizeof(arScore[0][0]); stu++) {`.  You're incrementing `cla` and `stu`, but you're checking `i` and `j` against the limits.  This is probably not what you wanted.  Too much copy'n'paste without quite enough editing — a common problem, and not only amongst beginners.

Answer (score 0):

You have written wrong variables,

```
for (cla = 0; i < sizeof(arScore) / sizeof(arScore[0]); cla++) {  // i instead of cla
        sum[cla] = 0;

        for (stu = 0; j < sizeof(arScore[0]) / sizeof(arScore[0][0]); stu++) {
            sum[cla] += arScore[cla][stu];   //j instead of stu
```

write this instead

```
for (cla = 0; cla < sizeof(arScore) / sizeof(arScore[0]); cla++) {
        sum[cla] = 0;

        for (stu = 0; stu < sizeof(arScore[0]) / sizeof(arScore[0][0]); stu++) {
            sum[cla] += arScore[cla][stu];
```

Comment: Oh my god, i feel so ashamed. Thanks for your kindness

Comment: @JangchunLee You can mark it as correct, if it was helpful